# Why is my Open Graph image not showing in LinkedIn 403 forbidden

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-403, share-open-graph

I have an Open Graph image. It appears to work, on various platforms, when I'm sharing my website address. But it does not display in LinkedIn.

I've checked my site on the Linkedin Post Inspector https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/inspect/

I get the following:

```
We cannot display a preview for this URL.
URL redirect trail: 403 Failure
```

What does that mean?

In my .htaccess file I have the following:

```
RewriteEngine on

# add www and turn on https in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# hide .html extension. To externally redirect /file.html to /file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

Could the 403 failure have anything to do with this?

UPDATE

HTML source:

```
<head>
    <title>...</title>
    <meta name="description" content="...">
    <meta property="og:image" content="https://www.xyz.co.uk/assets/images/example.png">
</head>
```

Comment: The 403 does not appear to have anything to do with the `.htaccess` file you posted. But if it did then it would likely have affected all "platforms", not just LinkedIn. Please post the relevant elements in your HTML source.